# Wrap text in code blocks in mod messages

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

Due to the letter format, when replying to our mod messages users may sometimes indent each of their paragraphs with four or more spaces, either deliberately or unwittingly turning them into code blocks.

Since the text is neither wrapped nor clipped with a scrollbar it ends up breaking the page if the paragraphs are really long. That makes it really hard for me to take their response seriously, especially if they don't know better.

Code blocks are already word-wrapped in chat, so perhaps it should be the same in mod messages.

I thought of an alternative of just disabling code blocks outright, but they may be useful for providing Markdown samples and so on, e.g. when offering guidance on formatting posts. Then again, I could just use `<pre>` tags instead for when I really need them. And of course, this assumes Markdown for code blocks can even be disabled on its own in the first place.

Comment: This *should* be as simple as adding `white-space: pre-wrap` (or `overflow: scroll`) to the right CSS rule. I could add it to SOUP, if I just knew what selector to use...